# How to use localstorage in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have an extension. On the options page i am setting options, that obvious. 
But i cant get localstorage to work. The options are binded to onclick event with jquery.
Example code how i am setting the values is like this:

```
localStorage["new_tab"]=$("#n_tab").attr('checked');
localStorage["anim"]=$("#anime").attr('checked');
localStorage["bov_e"]=$("#bov_e").attr('checked');
```

Where is the problem? Could you point me out in the right way?

Comment: `localStorage.set("itemName", valueHere)` and `localStorage.get("itemName")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `localStorage.setItem("itemName", valueHere)` to save the value, and `localStorage.getItem("itemName")` to retrieve it.

```
localStorage.setItem("new_tab", $("#n_tab").attr('checked'));
localStorage.setItem("anim", $("#anime").attr('checked'));
localStorage.setItem("bov_e", $("#bov_e").attr('checked'));

console.log(localStorage.getItem("new_tab"));
console.log(localStorage.getItem("anim"));
console.log(localStorage.getItem("bov_e"));
```

Comment: This line
`console.log(localStorage.get("hDomain"));`

 is giving me this error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Storage> has no method 'get'`

Comment: You mean something like this?
`localStorage.getItem("key");`

Comment: I did mean `getItem()` and `setItem()`. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

also you need to use

```
 .prop('checked')
```